# Can't go association backwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby and rails so be gentle.

i currently have 3 models (game, match, player, user)

game.rb

```
has_many :matches
```

match.rb

```
belongs_to :game
has_many :players
```

player.rb

```
belongs_to :match
belongs_to :user
```

now i want to fill those associations in the player model.

what i basically do:

players_controller.rb

```
def create
@game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
@match = @game.matches.find(params[:match_id])
@player = @match.players.create(params[:player])
@player.user = User.find(current_user.id)
end
```

after that i want to call in a view

```
<%= @player.user.email %>
```

then this error raises:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

so my question is what i do wrong going backwards in associations? it should be possible somehow

Comment: You're not showing us the associations in your user.rb, but I'm guessing they look like this: `has_many :players`

Comment: its an user 1:n player relation. user.rb `has_many :players`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `@player.save` after assigning to `@player.user`. Your associations are not "backwards", you simply need to save the record after updating any of its attributes to commit the changes to the database.

Currently your create method creates a new player via `@match.players.create(...)`. This is the last time your `player` object is written to the database. The next line, which assigns a user to the `user` association, is never saved.

And a note on style: If `current_player` is a player object, you should just be assigning it directly to `@player.user` instead of looking up the object you already have. The last line:

```
@player.user = User.find(current_user.id)
```

Should be written:

```
@player.user = current_user
```

Comment: added `@player.save` after `@player.user = User.find(current_user.id)` but still same error.

Comment: Try `@player.save!` and see if any errors are being raised. It's possible that one or more validations is preventing the player from being created.

Comment: modified `@player.user = User.find(current_user.id)` to `@player.user = current_user/.id`. tried both, even with `@player.save!`. same error still occurs

Comment: maybe it helps you that my routes.rb: `resources :games do resources :matches do resources :players end end` ?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the value of `@player.user` at the end of the create action? Are you sure there is an integer field called `user_id` in your players table? Have you tried creating a new player and assigning a user from `rails console`? There are a million more debugging steps to perform here, and we can't do them for you.

Comment: yes have tried inspecting the value of `@player.user`... its not nil. still haven't found the issue yet. also tried a complete reset of tables so that no corpses are in there. still haven't fixed that problem. guess i will rollback and implement this model again.. maybe i just got a typo anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `@player.save` after assigning the user attribute.